# Pyspark Code:- Using pyspark code, I want the below results

Tags: pyspark

I have a table like this with million records. ID is unique. Type holds three values - U, X, I.

| ID | Type | . Value. | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | U | 220 | 2020-06-12 |
| 2 | X | 120 | 2023-01-31 |
| 3 | I | 200 | 2019-01-10 |
| 4 | X | 150 | 2022-10-29 |
| 5 | U | 100 | 2022-05-12 |
| 6 | I | 80 | 2023-03-05 |

I need output in a way that it should have only entries of Type - “ I ” with the latest date and its value.

| ID. | Type. | Value. | Date. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | I | 80 | 2023-03-05 |

If the table has no entries of Type - “ I ”, it should look for Type - “ X ” and output should be with the latest date and its value.

| ID. | Type. | Value. | Date. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | X | 120 | 2023-01-31 |

If the table has no entries of Type - “ I ”, and  “ X ”, it should look for Type - “ U ” and output should be with the latest date and its value.

| ID. | Type. | Value. | Date. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | U | 100 | 2022-05-12 |

Comment: Your example table is already in the format that your want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If perhaps your table has some `ID` values with more than one row, and you need to choose a single row per ID (unlike your example frame), then you could use a window / partition by / order approach, as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

win = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("oType",F.desc("Date"))
(
    df
    .withColumn("oType",F.when(F.col("Type")=="U", F.lit("Z")).otherwise(F.col("Type")))
    .withColumn("row",F.row_number().over(win))
    .filter(F.col("row")==1)
    .drop("oType", "row")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a value to order the letters on. Then you can add a ranking per `letter_id`and `date`. Finally, you keep the first record.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("letter_id", desc("Date."))

df2 = (
    df
    .withColumn("letter_id", 
        when(col("Type.") == "I", 1)
       .when(col("Type.") == "X", 2)
       .otherwise(3)
    )
    .withColumn("rank", row_number().over(w))
    .filter(col("rank") == 1)
    .drop("rank", "letter_id")
)
```

I hope it helps,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

See the below implementation -

**Input Data**

```
data = [(1, 'U', 220, '2020-06-12'),
        (2, 'X', 120, '2023-01-31'),
        (3, 'I', 200, '2019-01-10'),
        (4, 'X', 150, '2022-10-29'),
        (5, 'U', 100, '2022-05-12'),
        (6, 'I', 80, '2023-03-05')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'Type', 'Value', 'Date'])
df.show()

+---+----+-----+----------+
| ID|Type|Value|      Date|
+---+----+-----+----------+
|  1|   U|  220|2020-06-12|
|  2|   X|  120|2023-01-31|
|  3|   I|  200|2019-01-10|
|  4|   X|  150|2022-10-29|
|  5|   U|  100|2022-05-12|
|  6|   I|   80|2023-03-05|
+---+----+-----+----------+
```

Now, below steps can be followed -

1. Define a window function to partition by Type and order by Date.
2. Get the latest row for each Type using the window function.
3. Filter the latest row for Type 'I'. 
   3(a). If no Type 'I' rows, filter the latest row for Type 'X' 
   3(b). If no Type 'X' rows, filter the latest row for Type 'U'

See below for more details -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Creating window
window = Window.partitionBy('Type').orderBy(desc('Date'))

# Fetching the latest row
latest_rows = df.select('ID', 'Type', 'Value', 'Date', first('Date').over(window).alias('latest_date')) \
                .filter('Date = latest_date') \
                .drop('latest_date')

# Filter for Type 'I'
i_df = latest_rows.filter('Type = "I"')

# If no Type 'I' rows, filter for Type 'X'
if i_df.count() == 0:
    x_df = latest_rows.filter('Type = "X"')
    # If no Type 'X' rows, filter  for Type 'U'
    if x_df.count() == 0:
        u_df = latest_rows.filter('Type = "U"')
        result = u_df
    else:
        result = x_df
else:
    result = i_df

result.show()

+---+----+-----+----------+
| ID|Type|Value|      Date|
+---+----+-----+----------+
|  6|   I|   80|2023-03-05|
+---+----+-----+----------+
```